# How to loop each list's column and assign them to an array (LWC)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

I have a list returned from apex (imperative). How can I loop through each column and assign them to an array in js?

I can't seem to populate the arrays properly. I can get the results but I cannot separate each column's data. Thanks in advance!

for example:

```
js code:

invoiceDt = [];
suppName = [];
suppId = [];

// call initData() then loop column sf_invoice_date__c then push to invoiceDt[]
```

apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Purchase_Order_Line__c> initData(){
    
    List<Purchase_Order_Line__c> initPoLines = [ 
        select sf_invoice_date__c
                , SF_Supplier_SMF__r.Name
                , SF_Supplier_SMF__r.Id
        from purchase_order_line__c 
        where sf_invoice_date__c <> ''
        order by sf_invoice_date__c];

    return initPoLines;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out that I previously did the logic correctly... However, I did not know that the fields/column names were CASE SENSITIVE. All good now. Pasting the code here in case it could help others.

js:

```
// previously was using 'sf_invoice_date__c'
get periodBox() {
    let periodOptions = [];
    for(let i=0; i<this.periodList.length; i++){
        periodOptions = [...periodOptions, { label: this.periodList[i].SF_Invoice_Date__c , value: this.periodList[i].SF_Invoice_Date__c }];
    }
    console.log('periodOptions >> ' , periodOptions);
    return periodOptions;
}
```